# how to use worry to make sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-form

If "worry" is a verb, can I say the following?

> I worry about you.

Also I found these two sentences from Google Translate, but in the first one "worried" is an adjective, but in the second is is a verb. I really don't get how should I use it.

> 1. He **worried** about his soldier sons in the war.
> 2. Your mother and I were very **worried** about you.

Comment: Actually, the first uses *worry* as a verb, and the second as an adjective. Both are valid and natural.

Answer (score 1):

***Worry*** is a verb and a noun, and ***worried*** is both the preterite (simple past) and past participle of that verb, and an adjective (as with many past participles).

When used as a verb, *worry* can take a normal object or a prepositional phrase.

> I don't want to **worry** you.

Here *you* is an object, and the whole things means that you don't want to cause the person to worry.

> I worry **about you**.

Here, *about* is a preposition indicating a topic. Just like you can "talk about going to the zoo", you can "worry about going to the zoo". It shows what the worry concerns.

You can use all the normal tenses with the verb *worry*, but you can also use *worried* as an adjective. If someone is *worried*, they are experiencing *worry* in the noun sense - an emotional or mental state associated with worrying. Both the noun and adjective sense can take a prepositional *about*, just like the verb.

If someone *is worried about* something, that is largely equivalent to saying that they *worry about* that thing.

All of your examples are correct and appropriate.

---

There are some other senses of *worry*, but they are sufficiently rarely used that I wouldn't worry about them for now.